# Start a Maven J2Me project in Eclipse and run it

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, java-me, project

I have a problem setting up my maven j2me project that I created in Eclipse.

I have the WTK 2.5.2 & SDK 3.0 installed and associated with Eclipse.
I created a project using j2me-simple archetype.
Copied the files from my previous J2Me project which was working!

but as I see, all the files that I know are missing. the Application descriptor, the J2Me packages lib that was there (Eclipse used to add these automatically) and lots of other stuff, what didn't I do?

Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created a project using j2me-simple archetype (...)

I'm not a J2ME expert but what you get when using the [j2me-simple](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-archetypes/j2me-simple/) archetype is a maven project using the [`j2me-maven-plugin`](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/j2me-maven-plugin/index.html) with default preconfigured settings that  you can tweak in various ways (there are lots of commented part in the generated `pom.xml`).

> but as I see, all the files that I know are missing. the Application descriptor, the J2Me packages lib that was there (Eclipse used to add these automatically) and lots of other stuff, what didn't I do?

I'm not sure but according to the documentation of the [`j2me-maven-plugin`](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/j2me-maven-plugin/index.html) site and the content of the generated `pom.xml`:

- the application descriptor: seems to be generated
- the J2Me packages lib that was there: most dependencies are commented

In my opinion, the generated project is not that complex if you are used to Maven and the various J2ME concepts involved in the configuration. If you are not, it might not be that easy to use though as it seems to offer several configuration options and will thus  require some configuration to match your needs (and flexibility generally induces some complexity in the configuration).

Comment: My solution was, to create a J2Me project, and just add it to maven, for now it works. I was just expecting Maven, to start a complete J2Me project, and not half automatically, and half manually, these files are a MUST in a J2Me project, and I expected Maven to handle them too.